# Leak detected in Instruments between two local vars

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, instruments

I was just playing with leaks and tried to create one intentionally. So, even it is silly to do something like this:

```
class LeakingObjectA{

    var strongRefToB:LeakingObjectB?

    deinit{ print("LeakingObjectA deinit")}
}

class LeakingObjectB{

    var strongRefToA:LeakingObjectA?

    deinit{ print("LeakingObjectB deinit")}
}
```

it is fine for the science purposes, and this creates a strong reference cycle.

Now inside `didMoveToView` I declare local constants and make a leak like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let a = LeakingObjectA()
        let b = LeakingObjectB()

        a.strongRefToB = b

        b.strongRefToA = a
    }
```

After a transition to another scene, the scene's `deinit` is called properly, but `deinits` from `a` and `b` instances **are not** actually called.

Also I say *leak* because this is actually detected in instruments as a leak:

[image]

Now there is a difference between what Instruments detect as leak if I declare these two local vars as properties of a scene:

```
class GameScene:SKScene {

    let a = LeakingObjectA()
    let b = LeakingObjectB()

    //...later in didMoveToView method I make a strong reference cycle like from the example above
}
```

Of course in this case, the scene's `deinit` is called as well after the transition, and same as above, `deinits` from `a` and `b` instances **are not** called (because of strong reference cycle).

Still, this is **not** detected as leak in Instruments... So what would be the reasonable explanation for this ?

Comment: Are you asking why it is a leak when you have them as local variables, but not when you make them global to the class?  Wouldn't this be because your instance is still accessible from some reference being held. But your local variables do not.  (If you were to treat this as a tree, your scene variables still has a branch attached, but your local variables are just floating off in space somewhere)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Hm, but that is not the case here if I understand you correctly... "The tree" (which is the scene) is gone here after the transition, and also the scene's deinit is called, so the strong references from the scene to those instances are gone as well. And obviously, those instances are still there (deinit from them is not called) but this is not detected as a leak, like in the case of local vars.

Comment: Oh I read it wrong,  I thought you said the scene's deinit was not being called,  so in both cases, the scene no longer exists. but the objects themselves still exist,  why are locals considered leaks and the globals not? is the question here.  At this point the only difference I can think of is the locals are on a stack, but the globals are in the heap

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah, you've understood it correctly this time. In both cases, those objects are alive, but just in the case of local vars the leak is detected when using the Instruments. About heap & stack theory ... I will have to search a bit...Do you have any way to prove it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not, otherwise I would be more helpful,  Maybe this can help you if you haven't seen it. http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Okay thanks, will read it.

Comment: unfortunately that is an old article, and instruments may have changed since then, but maybe he says something that might get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate this using the code below. The temp scene was properly deinitialized and both `LeakingObjectA` and `LeakingObjectB` showed up in the leaks instrument.

```
class LeakingObjectA {
    var strongRefToB:LeakingObjectB?
    deinit{ print("LeakingObjectA deinit")}
}

class LeakingObjectB { 
    var strongRefToA:LeakingObjectA?
    deinit{ print("LeakingObjectB deinit")}
}

class TempScene : SKScene {
    let a = LeakingObjectA()
    let b = LeakingObjectB()

    override init() {
        a.strongRefToB = b
        b.strongRefToA = a
        super.init(size: CGSizeZero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Deiniting temp scene")
    }
}

class ViewController {
    var tempScene: TempScene?
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tempScene = TempScene()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        tempScene = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. What iOS and Xcode do you use ?

Comment: I am on Yosemite, iOS 9.1 and Xcode 7.1.1 so it can happen that this behaviour is related to that fact. Still, I have to try your code and see what results I will get because your code is not really the same as mine (it is similar though, but transitioning is different). What kind of project have you used actually (SpriteKit game template or something else ) ?

Comment: I put that code in the MasterViewController in a UISplitViewController on iPad so I could swipe it back and forth. That's just what I had open; the first screen on a UITabBarController would be easier.

Comment: @Whirlwind can you please verify this is setup the way you described in your question and is leaking. Perhaps instruments has been improved because I am no longer seeing this type of behavior in iOS 9.3 Xcode 7.3 although I have seen similar issues in the past as you described. If it does leak for you and not for me I will award to Kevin for taking the time to test this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9d36bi7k81ypnf/LeakTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: @SkylerLauren I've tested the code and it turned out that I haven't tested everything properly. I appologize about that. I got very different results after I run the same code multiple times, and sometimes (only when properties are used) leaks are not detected, but sometimes are. So I guess this is related to Simulator version, or to the Xcode version...I don't really know. Have to upgrade my stuff obviously.